# Windows Server Backup Fails: There is not enough disk space to create the volume shadow copy

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, backup

We have a brand Dell PowerEdge  - Windows Server 2012 R2 is running ,
The server is an Active Directory Domain Controller - two NTFS partitions-C:\ FOR OS : 400 GB -  E:\ for data … I connect 1TB external drive for Windows Server Backup

I try to backup windows server  but  failed The message is:

```
There is not enough disk space to create the volume shadow copy
```

I can successfully backup while only including the System State and OS (C:) items. If I adjust the backup selection to include the Recovery partition, it fails. If I choose to include Bare Metal Recovery which implicitly includes EFI System Partition and Recovery Partition - it fails as well.

Comment: at first, maybe Veeam might be a better solution and second, you did not tell how big both partitions are. Please also format your question a bit better, a new line requires two spaces that it will be recognized

Answer (score 0):

Try something else. For instance, getting [Windows server backup to OneDrive](https://www.cbackup.com/articles/windows-server-backup-to-onedrive-6688.html), or other storage solution, to see if this problem would arise again.